# Unused variable error while attempting to detect invalid input

Tags: python-3.x

I'm relatively new to programming, so my friend suggested I try to make a customizable dice roller to get my feet wet. I've kinda hit a brick wall though and he's unavailable for comment. Here's my code:

```
#Die rolling simulator
import random as rnd

#Defines total as a set, y as the error detection, and allowed as a set of positive integer values.
total = set()
y = False
allowed = set("1234567890")

def dice_roll():
    y = False
    dice = input("What number of sides should your dice have? ")
    #tests if the input for "dice" is a positive whole number, then converts it to an integer.
    if dice and allowed.issuperset(dice):
        dice = int(dice)
        dice_rolls = input("How many times would you like to roll? ")
        if dice_rolls and allowed.issuperset(dice_rolls):
            dice_rolls = int(dice_rolls)
            while dice_rolls >= 1:
                dice_rolls -= 1
                roll = rnd.randint(1, dice)
                total.add(roll)
            print(total)
        else:
            print("Invalid input. Please use only numbers, no decimal points.")
            y = True
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Please use only numbers, no decimal points.")
        y = True

def lets_go():
    dice_roll()
    #tests if the error detection went off, repeats if it did.
    if y:
        print("Please try again.")
        lets_go()

lets_go()
```

What I'm trying to do here is ask for input on how many sides a die should have, and how many rolls of those dice the user wants. If they put in something that isn't a whole positive number, I want it to say "Invalid input. Please use only numbers, no decimal points. Please try again." and then have the code repeat. If everything goes well, it should just end after printing the results.

Whenever I run this, everything works fine, except the check for failed inputs. For example, if I put in the letter "f", the code correctly prints the "invalid input" sentence, but terminates the whole process there with no error message. I also have a warning claiming that y is an unused variable, even though I defined it at the beginning of the code and also inside of the dice_roll function. What's going on here?